# change font size and color in StreamWriter aspx.net

Tags: asp.net

I have this code and I don't know how to change font size and color in label, which should go in text file.Here is my code:

```
            if (!File.Exists(path))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine("Artikal                     Kol    Prize  Sum");

                            if (Label53.Text == "4")
                            {

                                string artikal = Label47.Text;

                                string Kol    = Label45.Text;
                                string Prize= Label48.Text;
                                string Sum= Label54.Text;

                                sw.WriteLine(artikal);
                                sw.WriteLine(Kol    + "X                              " + Prize+ "       " + Sum);
                            }
```

Comment: is your file `.txt`?

Comment: string path = @"c:\WebSite\restourant.txt";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try Code like below**

- You have to change below code as per your requirements. (This is just a code the way you can implement your code.)
- .aspx file

  `<asp:Button ID="btnCreateFile" Text="Create File" runat="server"/>`
- .aspx.cs file(code behind)

  `protected void btnCreateFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        CreateFile();
   }`

  ```
      private void CreateFile()
      {
          StringBuilder strBody = new StringBuilder();
          strBody.Append(@"<html " +
          "xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' " +
          "xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word'" +
          "xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>" +
          "<head><title>Time</title>");
          strBody.Append("<!--[if gte mso 9]>" +
                                   "<xml>" +
                                   "<w:WordDocument>" +
                                   "<w:View>Print</w:View>" +
                                   "<w:Zoom>90</w:Zoom>" +
                                   "<w:DoNotOptimizeForBrowser/>" +
                                   "</w:WordDocument>" +
                                   "</xml>" +
                                   "<![endif]-->");

          strBody.Append("<style>" +
                                  "<!-- /* Style Definitions */" +
                                  "@page Section1" +
                                  "   {size:8.5in 11.0in; " +
                                  "   margin:1.0in 1.25in 1.0in 1.25in ; " +
                                  "   mso-header-margin:.5in; " +
                                  "   mso-footer-margin:.5in; mso-paper-source:0;}" +
                                  " div.Section1" +
                                  "   {page:Section1;}" +
                                  "-->" +
                                 "</style></head>");

          strBody.Append("<body lang=EN-US style='tab-interval:.5in'>" +
                                  "<div class=Section1>" +
                                  "<h1>Time and tide wait for none</h1>" +
                                  "<p style='color:red'><I>" +
                                  DateTime.Now + "</I></p>" +
                                  "</div></body></html>");

          Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/msword");
          Response.AppendHeader("Content-disposition",
                                 "attachment; filename=mywosrd.doc");
          Response.Write(strBody);
      }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** Text files (if you mean files with a .txt extension that open in Notepad for
example) don't have such things like font-color or Etc.

- You can apply `color` and `font-style` using `Attributes` as below.

`Label45.Attributes["style"] = "color:red; font-weight:bold;";`

**But, Above code -It doesn't make reflect in your `.txt` file.**

so - you need to be
more specific: what file format do you mean; HTML would be simple,
presumably using  or CSS attributes; RTF would be achievable by using
the RichTextBox control; set the text, then manipulate the font etc
(something like below):

```
richTextBox1.Text = "Some Text";
richTextBox1.SelectAll();
richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Times New Roman", 20);
richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Aquamarine;
richTextBox1.SaveFile("C:\\restourant.rtf"); // or try with ".doc" file
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: i just need to print out this labels with different size,font and color in empty somekind file format,preffered in txt or xml format

Comment: @buba - if you want to print this Label with color , you can use just `window.print()` of Javascript.

Comment: sorry, i wanted to tell to write in somekind file format not print

Comment: can I send this labels in jepg format? And could it reflect this changes there?

Comment: could you write some example how to do this with html?

Comment: where do you want to color effect? In Screen or File or Print ?

Comment: use this link : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7341/Dynamically-generate-a-MS-Word-document-using-HTML

Comment: could it be c#, not visual basic

Comment: could you write here specific example, because I can't handle myself

Comment: See my another answer - it's just demo that can able you to create .doc file with your color text.

Comment: when I have more string builder ex: StringBuilder strBody2 = new StringBuilder(); StringBuilder strBody3 = new StringBuilder(); labels in that string builder isn't going in my doc file, so how to call more StringBuilder strBody2 = new StringBuilder(); in one method to write in one doc file?????

Comment: @buba - you can concatenate `StringBuilder` like - `strBody.Append(strBody2.ToString()).Append(strBody3.ToString()).Append("Another string"); `

Comment: doesn't working,it writes just labels from first stringBuilder